# KnockoutJS binding messes with input mask

Tags: knockout.js, maskedinput

I'm trying to apply an input mask to a telephone field. It works until I apply KnockoutJS binding, which removes the mask until the field receives focus.

Does not work: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8r6fe/

```
$('[data-mask]').each(function () {
    console.log('mask');
    $this = $(this);
    var mask = $this.attr('data-mask') || 'error...', mask_placeholder = $this.attr('data-mask-placeholder') || 'X';

    $this.mask(mask, {
        placeholder: mask_placeholder
    });
})


var ViewModel = function() {
    this.firstName = ko.observable("");
    this.lastName = ko.observable("");
    this.phone = ko.observable("");

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);

    this.firstName('John');
    this.lastName('Doe');
    this.phone('1231231234');
}; 
ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Works:
http://jsfiddle.net/gxhjn/

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        // Knockout tracks dependencies automatically. It knows that fullName depends on firstName and lastName, because these get called when evaluating fullName.
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth")); // This makes Knockout get to work

$('[data-mask]').each(function () {
    console.log('mask');
    $this = $(this);
    var mask = $this.attr('data-mask') || 'error...', mask_placeholder = $this.attr('data-mask-placeholder') || 'X';

    $this.mask(mask, {
        placeholder: mask_placeholder
    });
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think this is a knockout issue, but an issue with the way the masked input plugin is designed: Your initial value must match the mask criteria.  Even if you get rid of knockout and just use jQuery's `val()` function to set the value to "1231231234", you'll see the same behavior.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, missed your "works" link.  I was going to suggest a custom binding handler in the first place.  Looks like this is the way to go.  It applies the masking *after* the text has been updated by knockout, and then updates the view model with the new, masked value (if that's what you want):

```
ko.bindingHandlers.maskedInput = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.value.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext);
        $(element).mask(allBindings.get('mask'));
        valueAccessor()($(element).val());
    }
};
```

Here's your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8r6fe/3/

Comment: Check my "works" link. The value isn't in the proper format but the plugin masks it properly. In the "not works" link, if I were to move the input mask js to after the knockout binding it works properly.

Comment: Added a custom binding handler to show how this could be done.

Comment: Slight modification: If I do the handler on init instead of update, it handles the cases where my ajax result comes back null and there's no binding to be done.

Comment: Adding the handler seems to be breaking the two way binding. Even when I remove the update event and leave the empty handler it doesn't update the viewmodel. You can see in your example if you update the value and tab off phone.

Comment: Sorry Mike.  Without the init handler, no event handler is hooked up to pick up changes to the textbox.  I added that and it works now.