# Knockout masking

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm using Knockout.js, and I'm trying to use mask on user input.
When the user enter number, I want to use mask, and display it with commas. so 1000 will be 1,000

for that I have this function

```
function numberWithCommas(n) {
    var parts=n.toString().split(".");
    return parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
}
```

I don't get how should I use it to display it on the right way.

HTML (part of it)

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" id="myAmountInput" class="form-control" data-bind="value: myAmount">
</div>
```

JS (part of it)

```
define(['knockout', 'knockout-validation', 'services/changeup', 'moment', 'lodash', 'plugins/router'], function (ko, validation, changeup, moment, _, router) {
    function numberWithCommas(n) {
        var parts = n.toString().split(".");
        return parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
    }

    var timerId = setInterval(tick, 1000 * 10);

    var exports = {
        isRequestor: undefined,
        myAmount: ko.observable().extend({ required: true, number: true }),
        errors: ko.validation.group(this),
        activate: function (activationData) {
            var requestId = activationData;
            return changeup.getUserInfo().then(function (userInfo) {
                exports.userInfo = userInfo;
                return changeup.getRequest(requestId).then(function (request) {
                    exports.request = wrapRequest(request);
                    exports.isRequestor = request.username === userInfo.username;

                    if (exports.isRequestor) {
                        exports.myAmount(null);
                        exports.isResponder(true);
                    }
                    else {
                        var currentResponse = _.find(exports.request.responses(), function (r) { return r.username === userInfo.username; });
                        exports.isResponder(!!currentResponse);
                        exports.myAmount(currentResponse ? currentResponse.amount : null);
                    }
                    tick();
                });
            });
        }
    };
    return exports;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would create a Computed Observable and bind to that instead

```
this.myAmountWithCommas = ko.computed(function() {
        return numberWithCommas(this.myAmount());
    }, this);
```

[Computed Observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html)

example
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MXAYM/)

Update
added simple example using binding handler if you prefer to use that [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DYpM3/1/)

Comment: I've tried to do it, I didn't succeed to comine it into the code :\

Comment: does the jsfiddle example help?

Answer (score 0):

I just [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337488/knockoutjs-binding-messes-with-input-mask/22337812#22337812) about using a jQuery plugin for masking.  The answer involved how to use a custom binding handler to make the integration with knockout easier.  Might be something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

For the same purposes I'm using [jquery.maskedinput](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) plugin. It allows a user to more easily enter fixed width input where you would like them to enter the data in a certain format (dates,phone numbers, etc).

And custom binding handler

```
ko.bindingHandlers.mask = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var options = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()) || "";
        $(element).mask(options);
    }
};
```

And then you can use it on any DOM element

```
<input data-bind="value: Number, mask: '9,9999'"/>
```

The whole example on [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WzB5t/)